# The type initializer for 'Freezer.Utils.ZipDeployer' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-10

I am getting the error on my live server (`IIS10`) after deployment while using the `Freezer screenshot library`

https://github.com/haga-rak/Freezer/wiki

. The error is

`The type initializer for 'Freezer.Utils.ZipDeployer' threw an exception. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'ZipDeployer\\Temp' is denied.`

Other Tried approaches:

- I gave permission to a specific folder.
- I gave all the privileges to the app pool.

followed this link "[https://github.com/haga-rak/Freezer/issues/4"](https://github.com/haga-rak/Freezer/issues/4)

Here is the permission snapshot for my zipdeployer folder

[image]

Application Pool Advance settings:

[image]

Application Pool name in Site advance settings

[image]

Comment: under which application pool identity your application pool is running? which permissions you are assigned to "ZipDeployer\\Temp" folder? could you share a snapshot of folder permission?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal please check the updated question.

Comment: please remove the sensitive information from our image.like your machine name.

Comment: what is name of application pool ?

Comment: @dotnetstep .Net v4.5

Comment: @AtisamHameed Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

assign iis_iusrs,iusr permission to the folder and restart the iis. 
[image]

Comment: Still getting the same issue.

Comment: could you share your application pool advance setting?

Comment: Check the question please.

Comment: did you assign iuser permission to the folder? also set application pool permission IIS AppPool\apppool name

Comment: Already set application pool permission. But still its not working. The same error appeared.

Comment: which one is application pool permission?

Comment: .Net v4.5 is my App pool permission.

Comment: is this your name of the application pool? this is the default .net application pool. Click on the site in iis and select advance setting from action pane and check which application pool is assigned to the site[image](https://imgur.com/1lfpD5J). do not forget to add iusr permission.

Comment: Please check the question. I posted the site advance settings. you can see the application pool name here.

Comment: open the iis log file which plavced at this location "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\" Check the value of the cs-username field associated with the HTTP 401 error. This field contains the name of the authenticated user who accessed the IIS server.The anonymous user account is represented by a hyphen (-) in this field. Ensure that this account has permissions on the appropriate resources.

Comment: there are just ip's in cs-username. what should i do with those ip's?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using IIS 10 , things might have changed.

You have to give permission to user following way.

[image]

1. you have to go to that folder.
2. Right click -> Properties -> Security Tab
3. Add for new user
4. In Select user or groups screen , Location should be name of your computer and search for user IIS AppPool.NET 4.5 . ( It is like IIS AppPool\<>).
5. Try to give "Full Control" for check

If it works change permission later on as per your requirement.